# gulp-angular-protractor integration with cucumber

Tags: angular, cucumber, protractor, gulp-protractor

So, I've been writing very nice e2e tests using protractor (jasmine 2) but now my requirements have changed: I need to switch from Jasmine2 to Cucumber . As of now Cucumber is not supported directly anymore by Protractor. I tried a custom framework setup = > unsuccessful.
As mentioned I am using  [gulp-angular-protractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-protractor) which provide me with a great and easy work environment (turn-on/off webdriver while running tests, gulp command etc) and I would still like to keep it.

here is my  config :

package.json

```
...

  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "cucumber": "^0.10.2",
    "del": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-protractor": "^0.1.1",
...
```

gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('e2e', function(callback) {
    gulp
        .src(['./dist/**/*.e2e.js'])
        .pipe(gulpProtractorAngular({
            'configFile': 'protractor.conf.js',
            'debug': false,
            'autoStartStopServer': true
        }))
        .on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .on('end', callback);
});
```

protractor.conf.js

```
    exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    specs: ['dist/**/*.feature'],
    directConnect: true,
    exclude: [],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
    allScriptsTimeout: 110000,
    getPageTimeout: 100000,

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('cucumber'),
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'dist/**/*steps.js',
        format: 'pretty'
    },

    /**
     * ng2 related configuration
     *
     * useAllAngular2AppRoots: tells Protractor to wait for any angular2 apps on the page instead of just the one matching
     * `rootEl`
     *
     */
     useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

Dummy tests:

world.js

```
module.exports = function() {

  this.World = function World(callback) {
    this.prop = "Hello from the World!"; // this property will be available in step definitions

    this.greetings = function(name, callback) {
      console.log("\n----Hello " + name);
      callback();
    };

    callback(); // tell Cucumber we're finished and to use 'this' as the world instance
  };
}
```

login.component.feature

```
Feature: Sample

Scenario: First sample
Given this is the first sample

Scenario: Second sample
Given this is the second sample
```

login.component.steps.js

```
    var sampleSteps = function() {

    this.Given(/^this is the first sample$/, function (callback) {
      console.log("\n----" + this.prop);
      callback();
    });

    this.Given(/^this is the second sample$/, function (callback) {
      this.greetings("everybody", callback);
    });

};

module.exports = sampleSteps;
```

Project folder tree looks like this :
[image: Cucumber with protractor]

Issue: 
When I run gulp e2e I get :

```
launcher] Error: TypeError: require(...).run is not a function
```

at C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modules\gulp-angular-protractor\node_m
dules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:337:35
   at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modules\gulp-angular-protr
ctor\node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:7
7:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modules\gul
-angular-protractor\node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_m
dules\q\q.js:826:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modul
s\gulp-angular-protractor\node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\
ode_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
   at C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modules\gulp-angular-protractor\node_m
dules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:525:49
   at flush (C:\Users\Documents\dev\node_modules\gulp-angular-protractor
node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  why are you saying that Protractor does not support Cucumber? I mean, you need to use it as a custom FW, and you need do the following on your config file to be able to use Protractor-CucumberJS...

```
   framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    specs: [
        'e2e/features/*.feature'
    ],
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: './e2e/features/*/*.js',
        format: 'pretty',
        keepAlive: true
    }
```

And regarding to the gulp task, I've been using:

```
"gulp-protractor": "^2.1.0",
```

Having the task configured like this:

```
/**
 * run protractor
 */


var args = require('yargs').argv;

module.exports = function(gulp, plugins) {
    return function (done) {
        var protractorConfig = '',
            testConfig = '',
            environment = args.environment || 'devel',
            tag = args.tag || '@Sanity',
            baseUrl;

        if (!args.baseUrl) {
            baseUrl = 'XXXXXXXX';
        } else if (args.baseUrl.match(/^(?:https?\:)?\/\//)) {
            baseUrl = args.baseUrl;
        } else {
            baseUrl = 'XXXXXXXX' + args.baseUrl + '/';
        }

        switch(environment) {
            case 'devel' :
                protractorConfig = 'e2e/protractor.config.devel.js';
                testConfig = '../config/devel';
                break;
            case 'live'  :
                protractorConfig = 'e2e/protractor.config.live.js';
                testConfig = '../config/live';
                break;
            case 'remote' :
                protractorConfig = 'e2e/protractor.config.remote.js';
                testConfig = '../config/live';
                break;
            default:
            case 'build' :
                protractorConfig = 'e2e/protractor.config.build.js';
                testConfig = '../config/build';
                break;
        }

        gulp.src([
            'e2e/features/*.feature'
        ])
            .pipe(plugins.protractor.protractor({
                configFile: protractorConfig,
                args: [
                    '--verbose',
                    '--no-stackTrace',
                    '--params.test.config', testConfig,
                    '--baseUrl', baseUrl,
                    '--cucumberOpts.tags', tag
                ]
            }))
            .on('error', function() {
                done();
                process.exit(1);

            });
    };
};
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What I meant is : Protractor doesn't serve Cucumber out of the box anymore.
I made it work using  ["protractor-cucumber-framework"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber-framework) as suggested. Here is my protractor.conf:

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    specs: ['dist/**/*.feature'],
    directConnect: true,
    exclude: [],
    multiCapabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
    allScriptsTimeout: 110000,
    getPageTimeout: 100000,

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'dist/**/*steps.js',
        format: 'pretty',
        tags: '@Login',
        keepAlive: false
    },
//     cucumberOpts: {
//     require: 'dist/**/steps.js',
//     tags: '@dev',
//     format: 'progress',
//     profile: false,
//     'no-source': true
//   }

    /**
     * ng2 related configuration
     *
     * useAllAngular2AppRoots: tells Protractor to wait for any angular2 apps on the page instead of just the one matching
     * `rootEl`
     *
     */
     useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```